# Returning two values from a function in a loop

Tags: python, loops, return, function

I have a function:

```
def func(a,b,c):
    result = a+b+c
    error = np.sqrt(a+b+c)
    return result, error
```

However, **I have multiple pairs of a,b,c which I use to call the function as:**

```
parameters = [(a1,b1,c1),
              (a2,b2,c2),
              (a3,b3,c3)]

final_result,final_error = [func(*args) for args in parameters]
```

I get the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

How do I get the `final_result` to have all those values of `result` inside `func` and the same for `final_error` ?

If I just call

```
results = [func(*args) for args in parameters]
```

**it works fine, but `results` now contain both error and the result!**

I want `final_result` to contain the values of `a+b+c` for the different parameters and `final_error` to contain the values of `np.sqrt(a+b+c)`.

Comment: You want to have the result only?

Comment: `final_result, final_error = zip(*lst)` are you sure you need this? You'd raise exceptions in case of errors.

Comment: I want `final_result` to contain the values of `a+b+c` for the different parameters and `final_error` to contain the values of `np.sqrt(a+b+c)`

Comment: Please provide a sample snippet of the desired output.

Comment: @vaultah: I think he means the minium-square-root-deviation in terms of `error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import numpy as np

def func(a, b, c):
    result = a+b+c
    error = np.sqrt(a+b+c)
    return result, error

parameters = [(3,2,1),
              (4,5,6),
              (7,8,9)]

l = [func(*p) for p in parameters]
final_result, final_error = zip(*l)

print(l)   
print(final_result)
print(final_error)
```

Giving:

```
[(6, 2.4494897427831779), (15, 3.872983346207417), (24, 4.8989794855663558)]
(6, 15, 24)
(2.4494897427831779, 3.872983346207417, 4.8989794855663558)
```